# comment both js and asp at once

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm looking for a way to comment both js and asp.

`var myurl ="name.aspx?id=" + '<%= Request.QueryString["myid"].ToString() %>';`

As you can see above, I've a js statement which calls asp, I need a way to comment both at once, ie, with one comment. Individually I can comment each js with `//` and asp with `<%-- -->`. But I want to comment it once or a comment block where I can enclose the line above.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing with `<%-- -->`. This should comment whatever inside of it.

Comment: // will work for both in this case.

Comment: <%-- commented stuff, you will not see this in the page code --%>
// commented stuff, you will see it as a comment in the page code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you comment only JavaScript code, It will be enough:

```
<script>
   //var myurl ="name.aspx?id=" + '<%= Request.QueryString["myid"].ToString() %>';
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In VS, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, if default setting is used.